# Format date in a column using awk

Tags: bash, awk, gsub

I just want to fix this problem. I am running the code below

```
 awk -F, 'NR>1{gsub(/\:/,"",$4);gsub(/\-/,"",$4);gsub(/\.0/,"",$4);gsub(/\ /,",",$4);NF--}{$1=$1}1' OFS=, sample
```

**$cat sample**

```
 1,0,null,2014-11-24 08:15:18.0,1
 1,0,null,2014-11-24 08:15:16.0,1
```

The output is

```
1,0,null,2014-11-24 08:15:18.0,1
1,0,null,20141124,081516
```

My expected output:

```
1,0,null,20141124,081518,1
1,0,null,20141124,081516,1
```

Anyone who could help me with my code above?

Comment: `NR>1` means when the current line number is greater than 1. Did you mean `NF>1` when there is more than one field in the line?

Comment: I think it should be NR>0 to processed line 1. Another problem is this part **gsub(/\.0/,"",$4);** of my code because i believe this removes the 5th column.

Comment: `NR>0` is always true so just drop it.

Comment: The 5th column is being removed because you're telling awk to do it: take out `NF--`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/[-:]/,"",$4);sub(/ /,OFS,$4);sub(/\.0$/,"",$4)}1' OFS=, sample
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
$1 {
  gsub(/(\.0|[-:])/, "")
  gsub(/ /, ",")
  print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `gsub`, you are better off using `split`.

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
{
    split ($4, flds, /[- :.]/);
    $4 = flds[1] flds[2] flds[3] FS flds[4] flds[5] flds[6]
 }1' sample
1,0,null,20141124,081518,1
1,0,null,20141124,081516,1
```

- We set the input and output field separator in the `BEGIN` block to `,`.
- Using `split`, we break the forth field on `-`, `:`, `.` and space in to an array.
- We then re-construct the forth field by concatenating the array elements.
- `1` at the end will do default `awk` action, that is `print`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/[-:]|\.0/,"",$4); sub(/ /,OFS,$4)} 1' file
1,0,null,20141124,081518,1
1,0,null,20141124,081516,1
```

or:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ,]";OFS=","} {gsub(/-/,"",$4); gsub(/:|\.0/,"",$5)} 1' file
1,0,null,20141124,081518,1
1,0,null,20141124,081516,1
```